# Why does this React component return the string '0'

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

When I write this code, I expect my React Component to display nothing. However, it displays '0'. Why is this?

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const object = {
    array: []
  }

  return (
    <>
    {object.array && object.array.length && (
      <p>Test</p>
    )}
    </>  
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

See this code sandbox for a live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-lovelace-mmrkz

Comment: Because `object.array && object.array.length && ...` will evaluate to either the first 'falsy' value, or the last value if all the others are 'truthy'. `object.array.length` is presumably 0, so you get 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

React ignores `boolean` values by default, but does not ignore numbers.

Even if `array` is empty it is still a truthy value. If `array.length` equals to `0`, the paragraph is not being rendered since `0` is a falsy value, but still it (`array.length` - 0) gets rendered because basically `0` is a number.

I would suggest you to evaluate `array.length` into a boolean value, so it won't get rendered.

```
{object.array && !!object.array.length && (
```

Comment: `0` is falsy, but it's considering as `truthy`, why?

Comment: @Vencovsky Where is being considered as `truthy`?

Comment: Oh, now I see, it isn't truthy but it returns it's value, which is `0`